# Displaying item from xml <array-list> according to user selection

Tags: java, android, arrays, xml

So lets say I have spinner, from which I choose items, that are stored in string-array, and the user can choose from:

```
<string-array name="products_array">
    <item>Sugar</item>
    <item>Caster sugar</item>
    <item>Salt</item>
</string-array>
```

And I also have two more string-array lists, with another values:

```
 <string-array name="glass">
    <item>200</item>
    <item>180</item>
    <item>325</item>
</string-array>
```

and

```
<string-array name="tableSpoon">
    <item>25</item>
    <item>25</item>
    <item>30</item>
</string-array>
```

I have created the spinner and this is my onItemSelected method, which, as you can see, shows, which item from products_array list has been selected by users (by using log.i):

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    String selected = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
    Log.i("Spinner listener", "Item selected " + selected);
}
```

I have a layout file (fragment), in which I have the spinner and two textViews- one for glass array-list and one for tableSpoon array-list.

I want the user to select, lets say, Sugar, and for it to display from ***string-array glass*** accordingly 200 in my first TextView, and for the ***tableSpoon string-array*** 25 in my second TextView.

I want these values to be displayed in the exact order, as they all go on the list (Eg., Sugar goes with 200 and 25. Caster sugar goes with 180 and 25 etc.)

Without doubt, an if-else statement can be used, but given, that I will have quite a few values in all these lists, how can I do this more efficiently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your onItemSelected method get the position of the element selected for product array and save it in a variable like this

```
int index  = spinner1.getSelectedItemPosition(); // spinner1 is product spinner
```

and then get values from other two arrays for this position and set in your textviews like this

```
String [] array1 = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.glass);
  String [] array2 = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.tablespoon);
```

and then set values in your textviews

```
 textview1.setText(array1[index]);
    textview2.setText(array2[index]);
```

Answer (score 0):

**1.** Read string-array `glass` and `tableSpoon` from XML and store it into two  variable as below:

```
String [] glass = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.glass);
String [] tablespoon = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.tablespoon);
```

**2.** Inside `onItemSelected()` method, get the selected item `position` and use this `position` to get the `value` from array `glass` and `tableSpoon`.

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    ..........
    ..............

    // Set text
    firstTextView.setText(glass[position]);
    secondTextView.setText(tableSpoon[position]);
}
```

Hope this will help~